# Unable to deliver doc/ebooks to Kindle Fire (Gen 1) after deleting/recovering accounts.db

Tags: android, linux, root, kindle-fire

I just got a Kindle Fire D01E (i.e. Gen 1) released in 2011 and I've rooted it by using Saferoot (following the procedures [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=54123148&postcount=1)). That was successfully rooted by a root checker, and then I proceeded to install Google apps by using an old version of ES Explorer and some apk of Google Apps (following procedures [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/kindle-fire/development/how-to-kindle-fire-1-update-6-3-3-t2814955)). Everything is fine after that, and I also used some testing Google accounts to test those Apps.

Since I would like to remove those testing Google Accounts so that I can use the correct Google accounts, I backup and then deleted the file `/data/system/accounts.db`, and then removed the cookies of the Google Apps. However, after deleting that file and restart, the respective Amazon account is no longer able to deliver doc/eBooks (no matter eBook delivered from Amazon account, or pdf sent from the authorized email account) to the Kindle Fire, and the existing books in the Kindle Fire all become pure-Grey-rectangle (that should be the book cover) in the carousel, which can't be opened. I also saw that the Kindle's name disappeared and the Kindle was no longer logged in, thus I finally realized that `/data/system/accounts.db` stored not only the Google Account Info, but also the Amazon Account Into.

Without making the situation further complicated, I just simply tried to use the Kindle Fire to login the Amazon account again. It stated "connected" and I got my Kindle Fire Name back (cos the serial no. were still the same), but I'm still unable to deliver the eBooks (no matter old or new). The device's existing eBooks were still grey in color and can't be opened.

As I need those eBooks, I removed the new `/data/system/accounts.db` and use the backup of the old 'accounts.db` to replace the new one. However, the situation is still the same.

How can I use the eBook delivery again, and how can I get the existing grey books back?

Thanks!

Comment: Factory reset seems like the only option because it seems like your Android is broken. Also, you will not lose your books because they are stored in the cloud and are associated with your account and not with the device.

Comment: Thanks. I finally find a solution. It is a random trial and I don't know why it works, but it works. I enter the Google Play Store, search for the Kindle app, it is shown as "installed" (in fact I didn't install it). I clicked "Uninstall", a warning appeared: "This app is not installed by Google Play Store, continue?", and then I click "Yes". After restart, the ebooks' cover are back (and also accessible), and the eBook delivery works again.